# Jest Mocked data not loaded during test

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, next.js

I have a component that loads data from an API which I mocked for my test but it is not loaded as the test cannot find the element which contain the data.

component:

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";

import { businessDataActions } from "../store/business-data";
import { fetchBusinessListing } from "../services/business-listing";

import styles from "../styles/BizCard.module.css";
import BizCardItem from "./BizCardItem";

  const BizCard = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();  
  const [listing, setListing] = useState([]);  

  //load all listing
  const fetchListing = useCallback(async () => {
    dispatch(businessDataActions.setIsLoading({ isLoading: true }));    

    const ListingService = await fetchBusinessListing();
    if (ListingService.success) {
      setListing(ListingService.data);
    } else {
      dispatch(
        businessDataActions.setNotify({
          severity: "error",
          message: "Problem when fetching listing.",
          state: true,
        })
      );
    }
    dispatch(businessDataActions.setIsLoading({ isLoading: false }));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchListing();    
  }, []);

  const businessList = listing.map((item) => (
    <BizCardItem
      key={item.key}
      id={item.id}
      name={item.name}
      shortDescription={item.shortDescription}
      imageUrl={item.imageUrl}
    />
  ));

  return (
    <div className={styles.grid} role="grid">
      {businessList}
    </div>
  );
};
```

test file:

```
const bizListing = [
  ...some fake data
];
jest.mock("../../services/business-listing", () => {
  return function fakeListing() {
    return { success: true, data: bizListing };
  }
});

afterEach(cleanup);

describe('BizCard', () => {
    test("loading listing", async () => {      
      useSession.mockReturnValueOnce([null, false]);      
      
      await act(async () => {render(        
          <BizCard />        
      )});      
      
      const itemGrid = await screen.findAllByRole("gridcell");
      expect(itemGrid).not.toHaveLength(0);
    });
});
```

services/business-listing:

```
export const fetchBusinessListing = async() => {    
    try {      
      const response = await fetch(
        "/api/business"
      );
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Something went wrong!');
      }
      const data = await response.json();
      const loadedBusiness = [];
      
      for (const key in data) {
        let imgUrl =
          data[key].imageUrl !== "undefined" && data[key].imageUrl !== ""
            ? data[key].imageUrl
            : '/no-image.png';
            
          loadedBusiness.push({
            key: data[key]._id,
            id: data[key]._id,
            name: data[key].businessName,
            shortDescription: data[key].shortDescription,
            imageUrl: imgUrl,            
          });
      }      
      return { success: true, data: loadedBusiness };  
    } catch (error) {
      return ({success: false, message: error.message});
    }
}
```

The test executed with these returned:

```
TypeError: (0 , _businessListing.fetchBusinessListing) is not a function

      48 |     // }
      49 |     
    > 50 |     const ListingService = await fetchBusinessListing();

    Unable to find role="gridcell"
```

I can confirm gridcell is rendered when I am using browser.
Can anyone please shed some light on my problem

Comment: Could you also share what's in your `../services/business-listing` file?

Comment: hi @juliomalves, added `../services/business-listing` above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Manage to solve the problem myself, problem is with the mock:

```
jest.mock("../../services/business-listing", () => {
    return {
        fetchBusinessListing: jest.fn(() => { return { success: true, data: bizListing }}),
    }
});
```